# How does supervisord and nginx handle what tornado port is used?

Tags: nginx, tornado, supervisord

I am using supervisord to spool 2 instances of tornado on different ports and I use nginx as a reverse proxy to these ports. I have noticed that all traffic is directing to only one port. How does supervisord or nginx decide which instance of tornado is used when a user makes a request from the web service?

nginx config:

```
http {
    upstream frontends {
        server xx.xxx.x.xxx:8001;
        server xx.xxx.x.xxx:8002;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xx.xxx.x.xxx;

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [nginx docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#upstream):

> Requests are distributed according to the servers in round-robin manner with respect of the server weight.

By default, servers are given equal weight.  Are you *sure* all requests are going to one port?

Also note that `supervisord`'s role is simply process management - only nginx decides how to distribute traffic to the ports you've configured.

Comment: No I am not sure, but thank you for clearing up what upstream does